# Connecting bootstrap.dat to Bitcoin QT?

Tags: bitcoin-core

I have installed Bitcoin QT and I have also downloaded bootstrap.dat from a torrent. I am having trouble in adding bootstrap.dat to Bitcoin QT. Please guide me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Place bootstrap.dat in the bitcoin data directory and then start Bitcoin-Qt.  It will read the file to create the blockchain.  The file will be renamed to bootstrap.dat.old when this is completed to prevent reprocessing when Bitcoin-Qt is restarted.

You can locate the data directory by reading [**this**](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Data_directory).